# Ray remote call executes method, rather than returning ID

Tags: python, parallel-processing, ray

I am developing an hyper-parameter optimization function based on this Ray model: https://ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/auto_examples/plot_hyperparameter.html.

The method below, *perform_single_rs*, is analogous to the *evaluate_hyperparameters* method in the example, including a call to my train method, *trainmodel*, which follows.

```
@ray.remote(num_cpus=4)
def perform_single_rs(srch_num, X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test,
                      model=None, params=None,sample_weights=None, best_model_path=None, data_CNN=None):
    print('Search {0:3d}'.format(srch_num))
    model = create_model_cnn(params)
    best_model, X_train_CNN, X_test_CNN = \
        trainmodel(X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test, model=model,params=params,
                   sample_weights=sample_weights, best_model_path=best_model_path, data_CNN=data_CNN)
    best_model = load_model(best_model_path)
    results = {'best model': best_model,'params':p,
                'X_train_CNN': X_train_CNN, 'X_test_CNN': X_test_CNN}
    return results

def trainmodel(x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test,
                model=None, params=None, best_model_path=None, sample_weights=None,data_CNN=None):
    # Random search code gens params
    if params is None:
        #TODO remove squaring up of train/test from setmodelparams
        x_train_sq,x_test_sq,params = setmodelparams(x_train,x_test)
    else:
        # RS squares up train/test
        x_train_sq = x_train
        x_test_sq = x_test

    es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='min', verbose=1,
                   patience=25, min_delta=0.0001)
    # csv_logger = CSVLogger(os.path.join(OUTPUT_PATH, 'log_training_batch.log'), append=True)
    rlp = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.02, patience=10, verbose=1, mode='min',
                        min_delta=0.001, cooldown=1, min_lr=0.0001)
    mcp = ModelCheckpoint(str(best_model_path), monitor='val_loss', verbose=0,
                      save_best_only=True, save_weights_only=False, mode='min', period=1)
    y_cv = y_test


    history = model.fit(data_CNN['X_train'],
                        y_train,
                        epochs=params['epochs'],
                        verbose=50,
                        batch_size=params['batch_size'], shuffle=True,
                        validation_data=(data_CNN['X_cv'], y_cv),
                        callbacks=[es, mcp, rlp],
                        sample_weight=sample_weights
                        )

    # load best model for return
    return data_CNN['X_train'], data_CNN['X_test']
```

However, when I call the method, `rs_id = perform_single_rs.remote(...` *trainmodel* is executed and fitting begins. Why am I not receiving the Ray object ID as is expected with a remote call?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

When you invoke remote calls, `perform_single_rs` will be scheduled and run as soon as resources are available in your Ray cluster. So, it is normal that functions are invoked as soon as you run a remote function.

`rs_id` variable will receive all the objectIDs which are used to invoke the result of your remote call. You can see there are objectIDs in `rs_id` list by calling `print(rs_id)`.